# Android - Random XML Inflate Errors

Tags: android, xml

Stack overflow has been great to me in the past week in developing my first android app. Im having a very random problem though. Sometimes my app has a problem inflating the XML layout files. It's not one particular one, but when I change an XML file, it randomly force closes because I need to define layout_height on line 18. At least that's what it usually tells me. I normally just rewrite that View tag and it works fine but I would like some insight on to whats going on. Any help is appreciated!

Heres a sample XML that FCs because of the problem above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteFormDateTimeTest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="26dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteFormContact"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!--This would be line 18-->
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="26dp" 
    android:layout_below="@id/noteFormDateTimeTest"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noteFormTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="Note Title"
    android:layout_below="@id/noteFormContact"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noteFormBody"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lines="15"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Enter Text Here"
    android:layout_below="@id/noteFormTitle" />
<View 
    android:id="@+id/helper" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/noteFormSave"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Save"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/helper"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/noteFormDiscard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Discard"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/helper"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit, 3/17/2011 5:05PM CST:

Here is the activity that is being created on the FC:

```
package com.onyx.formapp23;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FormsNewNote extends Activity {    
    String  intentRowId, mIntentName, mIntentId, intentTitle, intentBody, dateTimeValue;
    int contactId;
    TextView contactHeader, dateTimeText;
    EditText titleEdit, bodyEdit;
    long  longRowId;
    Button submitBtn, discardBtn;
    private MyDbAdapter mDb = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.forms_newnote);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        intentRowId = extras.getString("rowId");
        if (intentRowId != null){
            longRowId = Long.decode(intentRowId);
        }
        mIntentId = extras.getString("contactId");
        mIntentName = extras.getString("contactName");
        intentTitle = extras.getString("title");
        intentBody = extras.getString("body");
        mDb = new MyDbAdapter(this);

        contactHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteFormContact);
        contactHeader.setText(mIntentId + ": " + mIntentName);

        dateTimeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteFormDateTimeTest);
        DateFormat dateFormat = (DateFormat) DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date());
        dateTimeText.setText((CharSequence) dateFormat);

        titleEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteFormTitle);
        if (intentTitle != null) {
            titleEdit.setText(intentTitle);
        }
        bodyEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteFormBody);
        if (intentBody != null) {
            bodyEdit.setText(intentBody);
        }

        submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noteFormSave);
        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String titleInsert = titleEdit.getText().toString();
                String bodyInsert = bodyEdit.getText().toString();
                if(titleInsert == null || bodyInsert == null){
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Please fill all fields before saving";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                } else if (intentRowId == null && titleInsert != null && bodyInsert != null){
                    try{
                    mDb.open();
                    mDb.createNote(Integer.parseInt(mIntentId), titleInsert, bodyInsert, dateTimeValue);
                    finish();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try{
                        mDb.open();
                        mDb.updateNote(longRowId, titleInsert, bodyInsert);
                        finish();
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "SQL Exception Thrown: " + e;
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
                }
        });
        discardBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noteFormDiscard);
        discardBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

The LogCat when the activity FC's:

```
I/ActivityManager(  316): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.onyx.formapp23/.FormsNewNote (has extras) }

D/AndroidRuntime(10518): Shutting down VM

W/dalvikvm(10518): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40138820)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(10518): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.onyx.formapp23/com.onyx.formapp23.FormsNewNote}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2664)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2680)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2034)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4628)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:870)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.onyx.formapp23.FormsNewNote.onCreate(FormsNewNote.java:42)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)

E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    ... 11 more

W/ActivityManager(  316):   Force finishing activity com.onyx.formapp23/.FormsNewNote

W/ActivityManager(  316):   Force finishing activity com.onyx.formapp23/.NotesList
```

And lastly, the thread stack:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2664  
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2680   
    ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2034  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4628    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 870  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 628 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Can you send the exact error message, or preferably the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brian,

Perhaps problem is with `dateTimeValue` you passed it to `CreateNote()` without ever initializing it.

Comment: This seems to be it. While I don't quite understand why it shows as an XML problem, after commenting out the date/time code, it loads just fine.  If you had a second to explain why it does that, I'd appreciate it. Im new to programming and don't quite understand everything just yet but I love it and want to understand as much as possible. Thanks for your time!

Comment: This line of your `logcat` lead me to believe it was an issue with your strings: `E/AndroidRuntime(10518): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.onyx.formapp23/com.onyx.formapp23.FormsNewNote}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String`.  Then from there checked each of the `String` variables you declared to make sure none of them were being accessed while null or uninitialized.

Comment: Sorry fo the late response. Thanks for the info. Hopefully this will help me pinpoint these sorts or problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in your build process. Just make cleaning before making project should solve your problems.

Comment: Tried cleaning and Android>Fix Properties multiple times, no luck :(